How can I write XML data to an XML file?
I am generating XML data that I need to write to an XML file and store in a directory on the server, making it accessible for future use. What is the best approach for writing this data to an XML file, and which directory on the server would be most appropriate for storing such files?

if the file needs to be accessible via browser, you can add it somewhere in the pub/media folder. If it should not be accessible you can write it anywhere else (almost). I would do it in the var folder.
And to generate it, you can actually generate it by constructing the content of the xml as a regular string with tags and values.
Or you can make use of the Magento\Framework\DataObject::toXml method. It does the same thing but it make it a bit easier.
If you try to generate an xml based on magento entities (products, categories, order, ...) you can call $entity->toXml(...) because all of the entities extend the DataObject class.
